# Create multiple object from instance

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I create multiple objects with a different name than an instance?

```
For i = 0 To totalcount - 1
    Dim Medio As New Reloj(rlj)
Next
```

Comment: Dim lstMedios As New List(of Reloj) .. For i = 0 To totalcount - 1 lstMedios.Add(New Reloj(rlj)) Next ?

Comment: You can't.  If you don't have a class named (Reloj) then your example won't compile. it will show 'Type not defined' error

Comment: @Rose I think the existence of a class named Reloj can be assumed. What he wants is to create multiple instances.

Comment: @Ljgazzano : What do you mean by "with a different name than an instance"?  Is N0Alias's comment helpful or are you looking to do something else?

Comment: Objects don't inherently have names. They may have corresponding keys in a collection of some sort or they may have a `Name` property but there's nothing inherent about an object that means that it has a name. A variable that an object is assigned to is not its name. You really need to provide a far better explanation of your issue.  Assume that too many words is better than not enough.